# Is there anyway to connect Lead Databse information to Program in Marketo by SOAP API

Tags: php, api, soap, drupal, marketo

I have a Drupal site with Marketo. This site has payment function as well.

When people buy tickets, I am sending their information to Lead Database in Marketo by [synclead](http://developers.marketo.com/documentation/soap/synclead/) (SOAP API). This function is working well.

I also want to make a relationship with user information in Lead Database with [Program](http://developers.marketo.com/documentation/getting-started/#programs-campaigns).

However I can't figure out how can I connect Lead Database and Program by SOAP API.
If someone know and done before please give me idea what method I can use.
Maybe I can use '[syncMObjects](http://developers.marketo.com/documentation/soap/sync-mobjects/)'....

**Memo**
Each ticket has difference Program ID from Marketo.

Comment: I gave up to use API and I used Post request. More detail is here. http://developers.marketo.com/blog/server-side-form-post/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track with the [syncMObject API](http://developers.marketo.com/documentation/soap/sync-mobjects/).

Each ticket purchase can be considered an Opportunity in Marketo. Opportunities are handled via MObject calls. You can use syncMObjects calls to create new Opportunities in Marketo.

There is a many-to-many relationship between Leads and Opportunities. Using an object called  OpportunityPersonRole, which contains an Opportunity ID and a Lead ID, you can link the Opportunity (the ticket sale) to the Lead (the person who purchased a ticket).

So first you would have to create an Opportunity for ticket. Then, you would make subsequent calls to associate Leads with this Opportunity.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I gave up to use SOAP API and I fixed by this way. http://developers.marketo.com/blog/server-side-form-post/ I don't understand is Opportunity and  Program is same thing?

Comment: Happy to help here. An Opportunity and a Program are different. In Marketo, an Opportunity represents a sales deal in Marketo, and a Program represents a marketing campaign. The Marketo object model is documented here (http://developers.marketo.com/documentation/getting-started/). Let me know if this explanation makes sense?

Comment: Thank you for your help. Ok, what I wanted to do. I would like to connect Lead info and Program. Is there any way to do it by API? (I used it post request instead)

Comment: I am not sure if this will answer your question, but I'll describe what is possible. You can add a lead to a static list via the Add Lead to List API. You can then associate a static list with a program in Marketo. So if a lead is a member of a static list that is in turn part of a program, then the lead will be a member of the program.